# Is this line of thought compatible with current physics thinking?

Tags: spacetime, time

The closer we get to the max speed of light, the faster time is moving from the perspective of the people "stationary" on Earth. This time speeding value is henceforth 'A'.

The closer we get to high enough gravity (black hole?) The slower time is moving from the perspective of people "stationary" on Earth. This time slowing value is henceforth 'B'

Let's say we are somehow traveling at a speed D which produces time speeding values A, while somehow having a gravity generator that produces gravity which causes time slowing B.  Now let's assume that A and B are such that the time speeding magnitude A is equal to the time slowing magnitude B.

Traveling in this fashion allows us to travel at or just below the max speed of light without time traveling problems.

Comment: you would have "living" problems because the magnitude  of the hypothetical "gravity generator" would be such as to spaghettify the body https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification

Comment: What "time traveling problems" do you think this solves ?

Answer (score 1):

Statement: "*The closer we get to the max speed of light, the faster time is moving from the perspective of the people "stationary" on Earth.*"

Not correct, Time does not speed up, it slows down for all observers in relative motion as they approach the speed of light. Earth people would see a Ship slowed in time (slow motion), and Ship would see Earth in slowed time. Both observers would experience time normally.

Time returns to normal (speeds up) for an Object as seen by an Observer who is approaching that Object's velocity.

Time Dilation is symmetrical to relative observers moving in inertial frames. That symmetry ends when an Observer switches from an inertial frame to an accelerated one (speed up, or slow down velocity), and there you get your "time problems".

Statement: "*Let's say we are somehow traveling at a speed D which produces time speeding values A, while somehow having a gravity generator that produces gravity which causes time slowing B. Now let's assume that A and B are such that the time speeding magnitude A is equal to the time slowing magnitude B.Traveling in this fashion allows us to travel at or just below the max speed of light without time traveling problems.*"

Gravity is equivalent to an accelerated frame ([Equivalence Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle)). Its effects are not symmetrical. Ship appears fast to Observer near Black Hole. Observer appears slow to a Ship outside the gravity well.

**Scenario 1: Ship drops off an Observer near a Black Hole**
At which point in this scenario, we have to ask, did Ship and Observer share the same reference frame? Ship parks itself outside a Blackhole and drops off the Observer. Ship takes off again to near lightspeed. Ship and Observer would have to gradually drop into their accelerated frames - lightspeed for the Ship, gravity well for Observer - to equal effect (if that even makes sense in General Relativity), otherwise this would create the first asymmetry in time.

Lets assume the effects of this gravity well on Observer closely matches that of our travelling Ship (which would need to also maintain an accelerated, not inertial frame) to result in this hypothetical symmetry in time. Ship returns, drops out of lightspeed. This creates another asymmetry if Ship and Observer do not perform a synchronized return to their original frames of reference. Again, I am guessing...

**Scenario 2: Ship with Gravity Generator returns to Earth**
Ship carrying around a Gravity Generator (Black Hole) would only work to slow time even further relative to Earth. So its effect on time would multiply, not counteract, luminal travel. Ship jumping in and out of lightspeed results in time asymmetries ("time problems"). Assuming one does not have a [Infinite Improbility Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(novel)).

So that defeats the purpose of avoiding "time problems". This assumes the Ship itself has a way of protecting the Pilot and everything else around him or her from atom-crushing gravity. By "time problems" I assume you mean: Ship returns to Earth only to find its children grown and enslaved on a Planet of the Apes?

You would also need an absurd amount of mass to generate that kind of gravity anyway. Gravity is a weak force. So you can add mass-energy problems to your set of time problems.

note - I am not a physicist. This is best guess. Nice question though.

You might find this interesting: [Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive).